# Проверка списка в списке

Tags: python

Есть два списка

```
a = [[2, 3, 7], [2, 5], [6, 7], [3, 4]]
b = [2, 3]
```

В списке b может быть много элементов, мне надо вывести списки из списка a, которые не содержат вообще не одного элемента из списка b. Тут должен быть ответ 6,7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для этого нужно использовать множество (`set`):

```
b = set(b)
for el in a:
    if not set(el)&b:
        print(el)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```py
a = [[2, 3, 7], [2, 5], [6, 7], [3, 4]]
b = [2, 3]

for l in a:
    for n in b:
        if n in l:
            break
    else:
        print(l)
```